# xquery order by date Time

Tags: datetime, sql-order-by, xquery

Say I have the following documents in my database: a_doc1, a_doc2, b_doc1, and b_doc2

All these documents are of the following format

```
<doc>
  ....
  <updatedTime>2011-02-07T14:41:02.133-05:00</updatedTime>
  ....
</doc
```

>

The value of the "updatedTime" element is inserted when the document is created using the fn:current-dateTime()

Now I am trying to do the following:

1. find all documents whose name starts with "a_"
2. order these documents by their `<updatedTime>` element in descending order
3. Return the first document name from the descending order

I tried the following:

```
for $doc_name in db:list()
  where fn:starts-with($doc_name, 'a_')
    order by xs:dateTime(doc($doc_name)/updatedTime) descending
      return $doc_name
```

Say "a_doc1" is created at **"2011-02-07T14:40:00.78-05:00"** and "a_doc2" is created at **"2011-02-07T14:41:02.133-05:00"**, the desired output is **a_doc2**. In short the document name(starting with a_) of the **most recent document** created must be returned.

When I try my sample code, the output returned is : [a_doc1, a_doc2]. 
The expected output is: [a_doc2, a_doc1].

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> order by dateTime(doc($doc_name)/updatedTime/text())
> ```

**Instead of this use**:

```
order by xs:dateTime(doc($doc_name)/updatedTime)
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified my xquery as you suggested (please see the edit in my post). But, the order by doesn't seem to work. order by xs:dateTime(doc($doc_name)/updatedTime) **descending** and order by xs:dateTime(doc($doc_name)/updatedTime) **ascending** gives the same result - [a_doc1, a_doc2]. Looks like the documents are being returned in the order of the for loop.

Comment: @sony: why don't you learn to provide a complete (but as minimal as possible) example? If you had done that, your question would have been answered long ago. Now, when people don't have an example to repro the issue, you only receive *guesses*

Comment: Sure. But, I assume that my question is complete now. I am not yet sure why the ordering of the document names doesn't work. Use of both ascending and descending gives the same result.

Comment: Looks like the function dateTime uses a different format. I modified the text nodes of the "updatedTime" nodes accordingly. Please see my edit, the node now contains values of the format - 2011-02-07T14:41:02.133-05:00. Then, I ran the xquery using xs:dateTime() function in the order by statement. Yet, The output is  [a_doc1, a_doc2] but not the expected output [a_doc2, a_doc1]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should use (xs: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema):

```
xs:dateTime($arg as xs:anyAtomicType?) as xs:dateTime?

Example:
xs:dateTime("1999-12-31T12:00:00")
```

instead of (fn: http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions)

```
fn:dateTime($arg1 as xs:date?, $arg2 as xs:time?) as xs:dateTime?

Example:
fn:dateTime(xs:date("1999-12-31"), xs:time("12:00:00"))
```